# In-browser XML transformations not working

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt

I've develop an XML stylesheet to transform a relatively simple XML file in VS2010. When I run XSLT Debugging in VS, it renders the expected output in a new window.

So I then added a link to the XSLT file in the source XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ABC.xslt"?>
```

However, when I view this file in a browser, I don't get the transformed result. In IE9, Firefox and Chrome

The XSLT (probably in a modified form) will be used by a third party to generate the final XML, so it's not essential it works - but it is a useful tool to demonstrate that the output from out database (which generates the starting XML), once transformed, will look like the final XML intended.

XML Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="abc.xslt"?>
<afterTreatmentSystemRequest>
    <afterTreatmentSystem>
        <ID>93073010005597</ID>
        <shipmentDate>20120330</shipmentDate>
        <technicalApprovalDate>20120330</technicalApprovalDate>
    </afterTreatmentSystem>
    <executionSettingsDate>2012-03-30T14:17:26</executionSettingsDate>
</afterTreatmentSystemRequest>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/afterTreatmentSystemRequest">
            <nsmajorassemblyai:storeAfterTreatmentSystemRequest category="MajorAssemblyAdapter" delta="true" version="2.10" xmlns:nsmajorassemblyai="http://majorassembly.mysite.com/ai">
                <requestHeader userId="d2vswen"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="afterTreatmentSystem" />
                <xsl:apply-templates select="executionSettingsDate" />
            </nsmajorassemblyai:storeAfterTreatmentSystemRequest>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="afterTreatmentSystem">
            <afterTreatmentSystem delta="true" dataCardAvailable="true">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <activeCustomer addressCity="" addressCountry="" addressStreet="" addressZip="" customerNumber="" firstname="" name=""/>
                <activeProductDate>
                    <xsl:attribute name="shipmentDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select="shipmentDate"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="technicalApprovalDate">
                        <xsl:value-of select="technicalApprovalDate"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </activeProductDate>
            </afterTreatmentSystem>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="executionSettingsDate">
            <executionSettings causation="plant" issueThreshold="err" systemPriority="2" unresolvedConflictAction="notifyAdmin" userId="d2vswen">
                <xsl:attribute name="date">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </executionSettings>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**:
I've re-inserted the XML and XSL segments - making sure they match the versions that are working well in VS2010. Following Dimitre's suggestion to use the IE Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), I can see that *some* of the transformation has taken place but I'm still missing the executionSettings element.

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nsmajorassemblyai:storeAfterTreatmentSystemRequest category="MajorAssemblyAdapter" delta="true" version="2.10" xmlns:nsmajorassemblyai="http://majorassembly.mysite.com/ai">
  <requestHeader userId="d2vswen" />
  <afterTreatmentSystem delta="true" dataCardAvailable="true" id="93073010005597">
    <activeCustomer addressCity="" addressCountry="" addressStreet="" addressZip="" customerNumber="" firstname="" name="" />
    <activeProductDate shipmentDate="20120330" technicalApprovalDate="20120331" />
  </afterTreatmentSystem>
  <executionSettings causation="plant" issueThreshold="err" systemPriority="2" unresolvedConflictAction="notifyAdmin" userId="d2vswen" date="2012-03-30T14:17:26" />
</nsmajorassemblyai:storeAfterTreatmentSystemRequest>
```

Comment: This would raise an error in VS -- the XML isn't a well-formed XML document. Please, correct. If you still get the same result, make sure the file `abc.xslt` is in the same directory as the XML file.

Comment: The XML is well-formed, and both files are in the same folder.

Comment: CJM: As said in my answer, the transformation performs OK and this can be verified. The browser doesn't display the result, because it isn't html.

Comment: The transformation hasn't performed OK (see comments on your question and the OP), but unfortunately, you've responded before I could do my updates! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous answer deleted as you fixed the example.

It works for me, both with saxon6 on the command line and IE (9) in the browser

[image]

Comment: Sorry David - in an attempt to check my OP, I made it worse! I added in the wrong XSLT - now corrected.

Comment: Ok, I'll re-craft the XML from my posted XML/XSLT and see if I can get similar results.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I did wrong initially, but the combination of XML + XSLT that I've developed in VS *does* transform correctly in IE9. I don't recall changing the VS version, so I can only assume that I initially copied something incorrectly when create my IE9 test version.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is performed correctly with IE9, but the rewult isn't displayed, as it isn't HTML.

To verify this, click <kbd>F12</kbd> and expand the elements in the HTML tab.

Comment: F12 is a useful trick that I'd overlooked! It shows that *some* of the transformation has taken place, but not all - the executionSettings element is missing.